# Maker's Call carrying objects or persons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoner, eidolon

Maker's Call:

> At 6th level, as a standard action, a summoner can call his eidolon to his side. This functions as dimension door, using the summoner’s caster level. When used, the eidolon appears adjacent to the summoner (or as close as possible if all adjacent spaces are occupied). If the eidolon is out of range, the ability is wasted. The summoner can use this ability once per day at 6th level, plus one additional time per day for every four levels beyond 6th.` [Source.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/#TOC-Maker-s-Call-Su-)

Looking at [the text on Dimension Door](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door):

> You can bring along objects as long as their weight doesn’t exceed your maximum load. You may also bring one additional willing Medium or smaller creature (carrying gear or objects up to its maximum load) or its equivalent per three caster levels.`

My question is this: Does this mean that the eidolon is functioning as though it cast dimension door, and can carry other characters/objects with it, or is this ignored because the summoner is the one performing the casting?

EDIT:
After consulting my DM, they said it makes sense that any eidolon can teleport back with its weapons/armor/equipment, which, by extension, implies that it can barrel into combat, grab two party members, and then teleport back to the summoner. I'm now looking for any reason why this would not be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, you only teleport your eidolon

The ability (as written) is clear on what it does:

> a summoner can call **his eidolon** to his side

Followed by:

> When used, **the eidolon** appears adjacent to the summoner (or as close as possible if all adjacent spaces are occupied).

This is different from *"a summoner can cast dimension door on his eidolon"*. If it did use those words, then the ability would work exactly as described on dimension door. Or if the ability made it clear that the eidolon could bring other creatures with him.

If the eidolon can carry another creature, he would bring her with him, as long as his maximum load isn't exceeded.

But if we ignore the initial text of the ability and read exclusively what dimension door says, then the ability wouldn't even work at all:

> Target: you and touched objects or other touched willing creatures
>
> **You** instantly transfer **yourself** from your current location to any other spot within range. **You** always arrive at exactly the spot desired – whether by simply visualizing the area or by stating direction.

This means that the caster (here, the summoner) would need to touch all creatures that would be teleported along with the initial target, which won't happen. The caster would be the one being instantly transferred from his position to another and so on.

However, there is no official clarification from the developers about this, as this is a question that rarely appears on the message boards. As such, the GM is free to allow the eidolon to bring others with him, as the ability is hardly too strong being on limited uses per day.

Comment: That's how I read it too, but that means in the same action, the summoner could touch a spider on the ceiling, use the ability, and suddenly have the eidolon and the spider on the ground nearby.